# Build jar with images inside in Intellij Idea13.1.1

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, resources

my problem is that when i build a jar with intellij 13.1.1 and include images to the jar, the path to the images are broken.
i get a nullpointerexception.
when i add the resource folder outside the jar and link the path as you can see in the code example it works. But my aim is to include the resources folder to the jar file, so that i only have one file.
i run ubuntu.

my project structure:

```
    res -> images -> button.gif
    src -> programm -> mainclass.java
```

---

code

```
    image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("res/images/animation.gif");
    this.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon( image)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load resources from within an exported .jar file, you cannot statically reference their location like you do when they are outside the jar. Depending on the path of the gif use either one of these:

```
final String internalImagePath = "res/images/animation.gif";

//example one
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(internalImagePath));

//example two
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MainClass.class.getResource(internalImagePath));
```

If the images are relative to the class containing this code, use the first loader example. If the images are relative to some class other than the one in which this code exists, use the second example.

Hope this helps. Cheers.